# How to fail a build in Jenkins dependent on a certain jar

Tags: java, maven, security, jenkins, building

Is there a way to fail a build in Jenkins if a certain jar is used in a Java Maven Project?

For example I know org.example:badartifact:1.0.1 has a security vulnerability. I told everyone about that, and they fixed their projects..., but maybe some third-party artifacts bring this with them as a transitive and nobody realizes that.

Or maybe someone down the line forgets this old bug...

So I would like to have a last check in Jenkins preferably, so that we don't end up with projects that have that special artifact included.

How do you handle situations like that, what tools do you use? (Whitelisting libs? Blacklisting libs?, etc)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible Maven solution**
You could have a company super POM ([parent POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) of all Maven projects within the company/department/team) and in that super POM configure the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/index.html), its [bannedDependencies rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) to ban any library, version or even scope. I have personally used this option even for trivial mistakes (i.e. junit not in test scope would make the build fail).

This solution is a centralized one and as such easier to maintain, however requires all the projects to have the same parent POM and developers could at any time change the parent pom and as such skip this governance. On the other hand, a centralized parent POM is really useful for dependencies Management, common profiles, reporting and so on.

*Note*: you cannot configure it in the Maven settings of the Jenkins server via an active by default profile, for instance, in order to have it applied to all running Maven build, because [Maven limits](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) customization of builds in profiles provided by the settings (it's a design choice, to limit external impact and as such have an easier troubleshooting). I've tried it in the past and hit the wall.

> Profiles in external files
>
> Profiles specified in external files (i.e in settings.xml or profiles.xml) are not portable in the strictest sense. Anything that seems to stand a high chance of changing the result of the build is restricted to the inline profiles in the POM. Things like repository lists could simply be a proprietary repository of approved artifacts, and won't change the outcome of the build. Therefore, you will only be able to modify the  and  sections, plus an extra  section

**Possible Jenkins solution**
If you want to have governance centralized in Jenkins directly, hence independently than Maven builds, I have applied these solutions in the past (and they perfectly work):

- [Jenkins Text Finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin): you can make the build fail in case a regex or a matching text was found as part of the build output. In your case, you could have a Jenkins build step executing always `mvn dependency:tree` and as such have as part of the build output the list of dependencies (even transitive). A Text Finder rule matching your banned dependency will then match it and fail the build.
- [Fail The Build Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin): similar to the one above, but with a centralize management of configured Failure Causes. Again, failures are based on matching text, but no build configuration is required: it will be applied by default to all builds.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution to do the job :)

With the [Maven License plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/), you can scan the 3rd party dependencies for your Maven project and produce a THIRD_PARTY.txt report (in the target/generated-sources/license folder).

Maven command line:

```
mvn license:aggregate-add-third-party
```

Next, you can use the [TextFinder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) to search the "unsafe" dependencies in the THIRD_PARTY.txt file (ex: org.example:badartifact:1.0.1) and change the status of the build if needed.

Another solution is to use a 3rd party tool to do that.

I'm doing some investigation with this one: http://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/

This tool can provide a list of 3rd party dependencies with vulnerability issues.